# Folding custom regular expressions in emacs?

Tags: regular-expressions, code-folding

Consider a pattern/regular expression I will call *reg* which matches multiple times in an  emacs buffer.  I want emacs to recognize all matches for *reg* and replace (temporarily, like folding) each matching text *match* with the result of a custom elisp function applied to that particular *match*, which I call *f(match)*. Furthermore the replaced text should be (customizable) highlighted (other color etc.) and if you move your cursor into an occurrence of *f(match)*, it should display the original *match* as long as the cursor is inside *match* (if you move it outside, it just shows *f(match)* again).

To have a simple example in mind, let *reg* be say `\[\[\!.*?\!\]\]` and the elisp function *f* could just translate all lower case letters in the matched text to upper case and vice versa. So for example `[[!HelloWorld1!]]` should be folded to `[[!hELLOwORLD1!]]`

In my particular case I want it to replace in a more complex way results of mathematical python calculations with the results in a latex file using pythontex.

Is there any package which could do this? If there are multiple packages, what would be the "state of the art" for doing something like this?

Comment: The built-in `occur` function or [loccur](https://github.com/fourier/loccur) package should get you part of the way there. Don't know of any out-of-the box solutions but you could build on occur with a custom function to replace match with f(match) to all matches except if point is in match.

Comment: The article [Higlight text ... with other texts](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2018/10/26/highlight-text-not-with-faces-but-with-other-texts/) describes something similar. One would have to adapt `my-highlight-regexp-with-string` to your purpose. (That should be relatively easy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Overlay-based solution

The [`preview.el`](https://github.com/jwiegley/auctex/blob/master/preview/preview.el) library of auctex shows how something like that can be done with overlays.

## Font-lock based solution

Another state-of-the-art package is [`hi-lock.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/hi-lock.el).
It does not support setting and filtering text properties out of the box.

[Paintover](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/paintover) is a modified reduced copy of hi-lock.el.
It serves as concept study for solving this question via `font-lock`.

### Reduction:

1. The package only provides `paintover-regexp` which corresponds to `highlight-regexp`.
2. Only the font-lock-mode support has been adapted. Overlays are not supported properly.

### Modification:

[`paintover-regexp`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/paintover/blob/d8ac17e994803bbc1a4c5de243bc70ed41f13349/paintover.el#L383) accepts in comparison to `highlight-regexp` two additional arguments:

1. an expression for a plist `PROPERTIES` with format `(PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2 ...)`.
   That is the plist provided for the `FACENAME` elements in `font-lock-keywords` entries as `'(face FACE PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2 ...)`.

   - Note the quote. The list is not evaluated.
   - nil is an acceptable `PROPERTIES` argument.
2. a filter function `FILTER`, it is called as `(FILTER '(face FACE PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2 ...))`
   The filter can modify the list argument and return the modified list that is used for the `FACENAME` element.

The prefix has changed from `hi-lock` to `paintover`.

### Notes:

1. You have to add the properties that you use in the FACENAME
    list yourself to `font-lock-extra-managed-props`.

### Test:

emacs-version: `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-04-12`

Solution to your test example:

- start `emacs -Q`
- Put [paintover.el](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/paintover/blob/master/paintover.el) somewhere in your `load-path` and run `(require 'paintover.el)`
- Find the file `test.tex` with contents below.
- Paste the Elisp code below to your `*scratch*` buffer and evaluate that buffer with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer`.

Contents of `test.tex`:

```
[[!HelloWorld1!]]

Second time: [[!This is the END!]] try again!

Let's try another time [[!Another Time!]].

Another case [[!SoMe String WiTH CaPITALS and lower case!]]
```

Paste to your `*scratch*` buffer:

```el
(defun invert-case (str)
  "Return new string with case-inverted characters from STR."
  (cl-map 'string
          (lambda (char)
            (let (case-fold-search)
              (cond
               ((string-match "[[:lower:]]" (string char))
                (upcase char))
               ((string-match "[[:upper:]]" (string char))
                (downcase char))
               (t char))))
          str))
;; Test: (invert-case "Hello You own mE $11")

(defun paintover-flush-once ()
  (message "paintover-flush-once")
  (remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'paintover-flush-once t)
  (font-lock-flush)
  (font-lock-ensure))

(with-current-buffer "test.tex"
  (let ((re "\\[\\[\\!\\(.*?\\)\\!\\]\\]"))
    (when (assoc-string re paintover-interactive-patterns)
      (paintover-unface-buffer re))
    (cl-pushnew 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props)
    (cl-pushnew 'cursor-sensor-function font-lock-extra-managed-props)
    (cursor-sensor-mode)
    (paintover-regexp
     re
     'paintover-yellow
     '(cursor-sensor-functions
       ((lambda (&rest _args) ;; sensor function
          (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'paintover-flush-once nil t))))
     (lambda (expr) ;; filter
       (append expr
               (and (null (paintover-in paintover-point (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
                    (list 'display (format "[[!%s!]]" (invert-case (match-string 1))))))))))
```